# Scene2d cyrillic font

Tags: libgdx, fonts, scene2d

I'm trying to use cyrillic(Russian) letters in *libgdx Scene2d*. I drop **default.fnt** and **default_0.png** (generated with **BMfont**) into folder assets of my Android project (other files such as **uiskin.atlas**,**uiskin.json**,**uiskin.png** are taken from libgdx examples).

main code:

```
    skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"));
    Label label1 = new Label("QWERTYqwertyЙЦУКЕНйцукен",skin);
```

uiskin.json:

```
    {
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: { default-font: { file: default.fnt } },
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color: {
    green: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 1, r: 0 },
    white: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 },
    red: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 1 },
    black: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 0 },
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$TintedDrawable: {
    dialogDim: { name: white, color: { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 0.45 } },
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button$ButtonStyle: {
    default: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round },
    toggle: { down: default-round-down, checked: default-round-down, up: default-round }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
    default: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round, font: default-font, fontColor: white },
    toggle: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round, checked: default-round-down, font: default-font, fontColor: white, downFontColor: red }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane$ScrollPaneStyle: {
    default: { vScroll: default-scroll, hScrollKnob: default-round-large, background: default-rect, hScroll: default-scroll, vScrollKnob: default-round-large }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SelectBox$SelectBoxStyle: {
    default: {
        font: default-font, fontColor: white, background: default-select,
        scrollStyle: default,
        listStyle: { font: default-font, selection: default-select-selection }
    }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SplitPane$SplitPaneStyle: {
    default-vertical: { handle: default-splitpane-vertical },
    default-horizontal: { handle: default-splitpane }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Window$WindowStyle: {
    default: { titleFont: default-font, background: default-window, titleFontColor: white },
    dialog: { titleFont: default-font, background: default-window, titleFontColor: white, stageBackground: dialogDim }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ProgressBar$ProgressBarStyle: {
    default-horizontal: { background: default-slider, knob: default-slider-knob },
    default-vertical: { background: default-slider, knob: default-round-large }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Slider$SliderStyle: {
    default-horizontal: { background: default-slider, knob: default-slider-knob },
    default-vertical: { background: default-slider, knob: default-round-large }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle: {
    default: { font: default-font, fontColor: white }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextField$TextFieldStyle: {
    default: { selection: selection, background: textfield, font: default-font, fontColor: white, cursor: cursor }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.CheckBox$CheckBoxStyle: {
    default: { checkboxOn: check-on, checkboxOff: check-off, font: default-font, fontColor: white }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.List$ListStyle: {
    default: { fontColorUnselected: white, selection: selection, fontColorSelected: white, font: default-font }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Touchpad$TouchpadStyle: {
    default: { background: default-pane, knob: default-round-large }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Tree$TreeStyle: {
    default: { minus: tree-minus, plus: tree-plus, selection: default-select-selection }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextTooltip$TextTooltipStyle: {
    default: {
        label: { font: default-font, fontColor: white },
        background: default-pane
    }
},
}
```

and get such result:

[image]

Where can be the problem?

Comment: probably, the problem was in the font file name, changed it to _"opensans.fnt"_ (for example) and in this row 
`com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: { default-font: { file: opensans.fnt } },`